# Why was Saruman sent to Middle Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth, istari

Gandalf a Maia (Spirit) was sent to Middle-Earth in human form to help the free peoples fight the evil of Sauron. Is the same reason for the Saruman sent to Middle-Earth ?